# Spring validation error message not converting placeholders

Tags: spring, validation

Here is how I define my property:

```
@Size(max = 30, message = "{user.validation.name.size}")
private String name;
```

And here is my message.properties:

```
user.validation.name.size=Your name must have less than {1} characters
```

But it displays "Your name must have less than 1 characters" instead of 30 characters. I tried to replace {1} by {max} and it shows "Your name must have less than max characters"

Comment: use  {2}  instead of {1}

Comment: It does not work. It displays "Your name must have less than 2 characters"